# Excel exporting sheets in different folders

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have main excel file with 10 sheets (sheet1...sheet10), and i need help with extracting (create new folder with sheet name) sheet5 and sheet6 in folder which link is in sheet1 n6 cell, and sheet7 and sheet8 in folder which link is in sheet1 n7 cell.sheets must be extracted without macros and formulas, only paste as values. For now i only have this which is creating workbooks in main file folder, i dont know how to setup extracting in diferent folders.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 
Dim xWs As Worksheet 
Dim xPath As String 
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

xWs.Copy 
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value 
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx" 
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False 
Next 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox ("Done.")

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at the statement "mkdir" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mkdir-statement . Also I recommend to you to use a specific sheet by codename not with `ActiveSheet`. Same for `ActiveWorkbook`: Change it to `ThisWorkbook`. While you're working on your code try to avoid all the lines with `Application.DisplayAlerts` and `.ScreenUpdating`. Put them in your code, when your code does what it should. The line `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value` doesn't make sense to me. :)

Comment: Some tips for your question: Try to structure your question more by giving examples, where is the data in your workbook and using paragraphs. :)

Comment: @Sergeij_Molotow: The line `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value` in the code is used to convert formulas to values.

Comment: Do you only want to copy the worksheets `Sheet5-Sheet8`? Do `N6` and `N7` contain the names of the subfolders for the mentioned worksheets? If not, please do clarify.

Comment: Yes, in N6 (d\arc\new) and N7 ( d\arc\new_elements) are paths of folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Export Single Worksheets to Workbooks

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    
    Const lName As String = "Sheet1"
    ' The following two lines are dependent on each other.
    Dim dExtension As String: dExtension = ".xlsx"
    Dim dFileFormat As XlFileFormat: dFileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    
    Dim lCellAddresses As Variant: lCellAddresses = Array("N6", "N7")
    Dim dNames As Variant: dNames = Array( _
        Array("Sheet5", "Sheet6"), _
        Array("Sheet7", "Sheet8"))
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = swb.Worksheets(lName)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim dFilePath As String
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
        For n = LBound(dNames) To UBound(dNames)
            If IsNumeric(Application.Match(sws.Name, dNames(n), 0)) Then

                sws.Copy
                Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook

                With dwb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
                    .Value = .Value
                End With

                dFilePath = CStr(lws.Range(lCellAddresses(n)).Value)
                If Right(dFilePath, 1) <> "\" Then dFilePath = dFilePath & "\"
                If Left(dExtension, 1) <> "." Then dExtension = "." & dExtension
                dFilePath = dFilePath & sws.Name & dExtension

                Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite: no confirmation
                dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath, FileFormat:=dFileFormat
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False

                Exit For

            End If
        Next n
    Next sws
                
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Worksheets exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: ty @VBasic2008, but is showing error on `For Each sws In wb.Worksheets`

Comment: Just replace `wb` with `swb`. Corrected.

Comment: its works perfect, ty VBasic2008